# Modx - Getting the current context

Tags: code-snippets, modx-revolution, modx-getresources

I have two contexts and I use a snippet to get the current context. The snippet is working properly, but when I use it in a `getResources` call, its not passing the snippet value.

```
     [[getResources? 
          &parents=`0`
          &limit=`10`
          &depth=`0`
          &tvFilters=`cb_show_in_top_bar_menu==1`
          &includeTVs=`1`
          &includeTVList=`cb_show_in_top_bar_menu,cb_hash_link_menu`              
          &tpl=`chk-top-menu-item`
          &sortdir=`ASC`
          &sortby=`menuindex`
          &context=`[[!context]]`
        ]]
```

The context snippet is

```
return $modx->context->key;
```

Can someone tell me how can this be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is exactly right, probably something to do with getResources. ~ try calling it uncached. if not, try setting your context key as a context setting so you can call it as [[++context_key]] or in your context snippet set it as a placeholder:

```
[[!context]]

[[!getResources? 
          &parents=`0`
          ... 
          &sortby=`menuindex`
          &context=`[[+context_key]]`
        ]]
```

!context

```
$key = $modx->context->key;

$modx->setPlaceholder('context_key', $key);

return;
```